# remove self-closed unnecessary markup xslt

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt

I am using the following XSLT:

https://gist.github.com/4402884

Where the following template  does the transformation to render html output as follows:

```
<li>
  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px"> content </div>

  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px">content </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px"> content </div>

  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px">content </div>
</li>
.
.
.
```

so on..
Actual XSLT doing the job to get the two column layout like this:

```
A-----B
C-----D
E-----F
```

where each row is an 'li' item

```
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$CurPos mod 2 =1">
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;li style=&quot;width:610px; height:290px; &quot;&gt;</xsl:text>      
       <div class="content-left" style="width:290px; height:290px;float:left;">
            <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="$CurPos"/><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></h4></span>
            <span class="Desc" style="display:block; width:280px;"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@Comments,0,200)"/>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(@Comments) &gt; 200">…</xsl:if><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" class="ReadMore"> Read More</a></span>
        </div>

        <div class="content-right" style="float:right; width:290px; height:290px;">
            <xsl:if test="$CurPos != $LastRow ">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@PublishingRollupImage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="$LastRow"/><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@Title"/></h4></span>
                <span class="Desc" style="display:block; width:280px;"><xsl:value-of select="substring(following-sibling::*[1]/@Comments,0,200)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(following-sibling::*[1]/@Comments) &gt; 200">…</xsl:if>
                <a href="{$SibSafeLinkUrl}" class="ReadMore"> Read More</a></span>
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/li&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Sadly, however Inernet Explorer produces unnecessary self-closed tags like this(just IE), FF and chrome render it correctly...

```
<li>
  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px"> content </div>

  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px">content </div>
</li></li/></li/>

<li>
  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px"> content </div>

  <div class="content-left" style="float:left; width:300px">content </div>
</li></li/></li/>
```

How do I get rid of those unwanted self-closed weird looking 'li' tags? Because i need the exact html structure for a jquery slider plugin to work, because of the unwanted tags, slider is misbehaving.

This is in IE:
[IE http://www.imagesup.net/?di=9135673644516](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=9135673644516)

This is in FireFox:
[FF http://www.imagesup.net/?di=11135673652612](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=11135673652612)

Comment: If you avoid using DOE, it is likely you won't get unexplainable output.

Comment: Can you gives us a complete sample input?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Turns out the unexplainable output seems to appear only in IE 8. IE 9, chrome, FireFox do fine... Is there anyway to target a specific version of browser in XSLT as we do in CSS?

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya, AFAIK FF doesn't support DOE -- this proves that your problem is due to using DOE -- it also shows one of the reasons why one shouldn't use DOE -- what may work with one XSLT processor (browser), may not work with another.

Comment: Actually, what I see are not _self-closed_ 'li' tags, but _additional_ closing tags (`</li>` instead of `<li/>`). Coincidentally, [Tim C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14084059/653295)'s solution might resolve this :]

Comment: Whoa, looking at it again, I now see the strange tags `</li/>` with 2 slashes…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this will solve your problem, but I would strongly consider re-jigging your xsl:choose statement. I am guessing you are using disable-output-escaping because if you tried to write your XSLT like the following sample, it would not be well-formed XML, and so not valid. (I've abridged the code sample for brevity).

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$CurPos mod 2 =1">
       <li>  
       <div class="content-left">
           <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
           <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@PublishingRollupImage" />
        </div>
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise>
         </li>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

What you are trying to achieve is to group together pairs of element, so you select the elements in position 1, 3, 5, etc. and then output that element and the following one.

What you could do instead, to avoid the use of disable-output-escaping, is to re-write it like this.

```
<xsl:if test="$CurPos mod 2 =1">
   <li>  
      <div class="content-left">
         <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="content-right">
         <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@PublishingRollupImage" />
      </div>
   </li>
</xsl:if>
```

This is now well-formed, and the **li** elements are being output directly. Whether this solves your problem or not, it is probably worth doing.